# Cant open *.sln files with Visual Studio anymore

Tags: visual-studio

I was working on a xamarin.forms project when

```
System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found
```

came up on a constructor. According to [the Xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/124472/default-constructor-not-found-exception) this is a VS bug, which I tried to fix with

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe -i
```

While this did not solve my constructor problem, I found another way to achieve my goal and I worked out a solution without interfaces. Netherless, after restarting my PC, it seems like Visual Studio wont open .sln files anymore. When I double click them a window which tells me to select an application to open the file appears (Image below).

[image]

I also cant use the VS installer anymore. There is no repair or uninstall option and if I click install it fails because the Visual Studio directory is not empty (Image below).

[image]

Only option to use VS at the moment is to find the exe file of VS and open it as administrator (without administrator it also fails). From there I can just browse my projects and open .sln files.

Any ways to fix this? How to clean uninstall VS without installer?

Comment: The unfortunate truth is that once the installer fails, you’ll most likely have to reinstall Windows. Visual Studio consists of tens of thousands of components. But maybe there’s a better solution by now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking first a backup image of your system disk and create the boot media
for restoring it in case of catastrophic failure.
One product that you could use is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html)
and its [Bootable media](https://www.ubackup.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html).

Once you have an escape path, you may try:

- In an elevated CMD run `vs_version.exe /uninstall /force`
- Forcibly uninstall the installed bundle by:

  - In Programs and Features, right-click "Visual Studio" and select "Change"
    to get it started
  - Cancel the installation
  - Go to `%TEMP%` and look for the most
    recent log file named something like `dd_vs_*.log`.
  - The first line in that log will contain a path. For example
    "path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{a60a492e-b5eb-4218-a9e6-f38d18a7dbaf}\vs_enterprise.exe"
  - Run it like this in an elevated CMD:

    ```
    "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{a60a492e-b5eb-4218-a9e6-f38d18a7dbaf}\vs_enterprise.exe" /uninstall /force
    ```
- Try the
  [VisualStudioUninstaller](https://github.com/microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller)
- Try
  [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/)
  to see if it can remove all traces of it, even without running the
  uninstaller (it might remove too much).

If everything fails, you might need to reinstall Windows to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the VS 2019 directory by hand. From there it was possible to click install again in the Installer. After installing again I just went repair and it worked again.